# Overwrite unique pair SQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table called `news` that have a unique pair `(idCategory, ImportantNews)`. In short, the `news` have one category and i wanna have one featured news by category. The problem is that I want to insert the new record even if the pair exists in the table.

I have a unique index for the columns (idCategory, importantNews), so false will create a duplicate key error. What I want is create a trigger or something similar that detect if exists some record that have the same (idCategory, importantNews) as the insert/update. Then, the trigger will update the actual record, setting the importantNews as null and insert the new row.

Example:

One row:

```
(id,idCategory,importantNews) .> (1,1,TRUE);
```

If I execute the next query-> `INSERT INTO news (1,True)`

the table stays like this

2 rows

```
(id,idCategory,importantNews) .> (1,1,NULL)

(id,idCategory,importantNews) .> (2,1,TRUE)
```

Comment: 'the table stays like this' - not it doesn't an insert won't amend an existing row. Did you mean to say this is what I want the table to look like after a second insert for idCategory,importantNews. I am also not clear what happens if you insert 1,false or 1,maybe or if such things can happen at all.

Comment: You cannot insert one record and update another in one query. 2 queries needed.

Comment: *If I execute the next query-> `INSERT INTO news (1,True)`* ... you will get the error "values count do not match fields count".

Comment: 'so false will create a duplicate key error.' only if  you submit another row with false, it won't create a duplicate key error if have already inserted 1,true and then 1,false.

Comment: 'What I want is create a trigger ' - you can't mysql will not allow you to update the table which fired the trigger. - Is there any need to do any of this surely you can just select the most recent id for a category??